# Adjust CSV Shape (all values are under the last column)

Tags: csv, dataset, rows

I guess it's a dummy question but - probably using wrong keywords - I spent a significant amount of time trying to solve it.

I downloaded bank-additional-full.csv dataset from  https://www.kaggle.com/volodymyrgavrysh/bank-marketing-campaigns-dataset and here it's what I can see :

[image]

I really don't know how to adjust it in order to have values under the related columns
(without modifying it externally via Excel)

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Ok.... sorry guys, I realized how to do it just immediately after posting:

```
 df = pd.read_csv("datasets/bank-additional-full.csv", delimiter = ";")
```